# To read a big file which are in Gigs fastly in PERL

Tags: perl

We are currently reading the file line by line which delays to read and complete for all.

we would need to read the file fastly and prgoress with our commands.

the commands which i tried using fork and array just displays me the first set of lines only and not proceeding with pther sets.

please help on it.

Comment: What do you want to do with it other than just read it?

Answer (score 3):

Reading a large file takes a fair bit of time - disks are slow, after all.  Before you start looking at Perl, first try (assuming you're on a unix-type system):

```
time cat /path/to/your/large/file >/dev/null
```

The output will tell you how long it takes to just read that file from disk without doing anything to it.  Alternately, open the file in your favorite text editor and time how long it takes to load.  Once you have that time, compare it to how long your Perl program takes to read the file.  Unless the Perl program takes significantly longer, you're not likely to be able to do anything about it because the time is being spent on getting the data from disk rather than on processing it.

Of course, that's assuming that you actually do need to read the entire file.  If you can get by with only reading specific parts of it, then you could create an index file and use that to jump directly to the part that's of interest, but you haven't provided enough information for us to tell whether that would apply to your case or not.

If you need more specific help, please provide a better description of what you mean to accomplish and a small, runnable piece of Perl code which shows how you're currently reading and processing the file so that we can see whether you're doing anything particularly inefficient that can be improved on.